# Azure functions output caching

Tags: api, azure, azure-functions, azure-caching

I am creating Azure functions to return data from a database (Azure AS). I will be returning same data for all the requests, so caching the output seems like a good idea as the data changes only once a day

What are my options here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options listed from most simple to most complex:

1. One option is to use static variables - but since the process can get recycled very quickly (assume every few minutes), that may not help much.
2. **Cache via storage (Blob / Table)**.  Your function can first try to read from the table, if missing, it can then read from the database and save back to the table.  You could have a second timer function that deletes old cache entries every N hours.
   **I'd recommend starting here**.
3. Azure Functions can still run arbitrary code, you could call out to any other caching service (ie, Redis) and use the same patterns that you'd use in ASP.Net.

Comment: Wouldn't point 1 only apply to Function Apps in the Consumption Plan? Functions in the App Service plan have dedicated VMs, so they wouldn't be recycled. (???)

Comment: Dedicated VMs can still get rebooted at random times. Although it's definitely less frequent than consumption so could be often ignored. 
Worst case scenario, perhaps there was a power loss to the machine or a hardware failure - dedicated just means that in such a case, the machine (or a replacement) will immediately spin up and be available.